# Do you still use MyISAM or prefer Aria storage engine?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam, percona-server, storage-engine

If Aria storage engine (previously called Maria) is the "new" MyISAM, which supports transaction and automatic crash recovery:

- Why still use MyISAM ?
- Should changing storage engine from MyISAM to Aria be a problem? (lose index or something)

Comment: Hi jcho360, I'm not sure what your question is here. Do you have a specific question about using either Maria or MyISAM? Otherwise this seems just to be an opinion question, which is frowned upon.

Comment: @DTest I thinks that an easier way to ask could be, Maria Vs MyIsam. or why should we use MyIsam if Maria suppose to be better?

Comment: Maria is a complete DBMS, MyISAM is a storage engine for MySQL. I don't see how you could change one for the other

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please take a look to this link: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_%28storage_engine%29

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: jcho360 is right. **Maria** is the engine, **MariaDB** is the DBMS (where Maria is avaialble).

Comment: Interesting. This is **really** getting confusing. Is Maria something different than the (presumably dead?) Falcon engine? That talk is from 2009 is this still valid?

Comment: To clarify things: the storage engine is now called [**Aria**](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/aria), to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: @ypercube: so why isn't Maria not listed as a valid storage engine in the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html

Comment: No idea how these things are done (what engines are included in the official MySQL product). The Aria engine is used by MariaDB product. Maybe it has to do with licences, I don't know.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: This doesn't answer your question but the [engines included in MariaDB](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-features) page has the list. Obviously, Oracle corp. decides which engines are compiled into MySQL. Why it doesn't include Aria, one can make guesses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is very interesting this question would come up because a similar question was asked back in January 2011 ( [When is the right time to use MariaDB instead of MySQL, and Why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14/when-is-the-right-time-to-use-mariadb-instead-of-mysql-and-why) ). Giving thought to that 16-month-old question and [*how I answered it in April 2011*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2225/877), here are my answers to your immediate questions:

> Why still using MyISAM ?

MyISAM still has features that are unique and useful for small datasets and read slaves in HA setups

- Deadlocking is impossible in low-write, heavy-read environments

  - [MySQL MyISAM Locking question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/mysql-myisam-locking-question/8410#8410)
  - [Benefits of table level locking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/benefits-of-table-level-locking/5782#5782)
- Converting to Fixed Row Format creates bigger tables but increases query performance in terms of

  - character string comparison/compression : [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643)
  - read/write speed : [Which is faster, InnoDB or MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/which-is-faster-innodb-or-myisam/17434#17434)
- Full Faith and Confidence

  - InnoDB has become the de facto standard of Transactional Storage Engines for MySQL. XtraDB is being accepted and used as well among the Percona Server community. Full faith and confidence seems to rest with InnoDB over XtraDB as present. This could easily change over time as more recognize XtraDB's superior features.
  - The same equally applies to MyISAM vs Aria. Full faith and confidence currently rests with MyISAM. An example of those who do not have Full faith and confidence are Drizzle users (Drizzle have abandoned MyISAM as an Optional Storage Engine and relegated it to temp table use only)

> To changes storage engine from MyISAM to Maria should it be a problem? (lose index or something)

If you mysqldump the data and the schema into two separate files, you can always import data into table with either the MyISAM or Aria storage engines. Just keep around the data only mysqldump to be sure.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was reading a book from 2009 and it said, Maria is the future MyIsam (well now Maria = Aria) and still in production.

Comment: Is it up to date?